# Google Consent Mode from GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am implementing Google Analytics with Google Consent Mode.
It works with these two scripts. It will actually track without setting cookies, as meant to.

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag("consent", "default", {
        ad_storage: "denied",
        analytics_storage: "denied",
        wait_for_update: 500
    });
    gtag('set', 'url_passthrough', true);
</script>
```

And

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=MYCODE"></script>
<script>
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'MYCODE');
</script>
```

But if I remove the last section and track through GTM instead, it does not work.
It only tracks if I change 'denied' to 'granted'.

Anyone knows how to implement Analytics and Consent Mode through GTM?

Comment: Were you able to make it work? I am also facing exact same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not. Were you?

Comment: Nope. Couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my advice.

1. Create 2 variables that can read the status of your consent cookie. The goal is to have them return a value of `granted` or `denied` for the marketing and statistics value of your cookie. You can do this through a lookup table or a custom javascript variable, depends on what you like to work with. For instance, Cookiebot has [their own variable in the Template Gallery](https://tagmanager.google.com/gallery/#/owners/cybotcorp/templates/gtm-templates-cookiebot-variable) which you can add to your workspace and it will return a value of `|preferences|marketing|statistics|` depending on what level of consent is given by a user. It does this by reading their own cookie and parsing it into an easy pipe-separated format.
2. Once you have added the Cookiebot Consent State variable, go ahead and create a lookup table (regex type) variable. In it, add the recently created Cookiebot Consent State variable as the Input Variable. Add a row and type in `marketing` for Pattern and add `granted` as the Output value. Enable Set Default Value and add `denied`.
   [View example Tag setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kcfi.png) After you are done, copy the tag and make one for `statistics` with the same values.
3. Now, Install Simo Ahava's Google Consent Mode tag template from within
   the Template Gallery (gif explaining where to find it:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0MnU.jpg)
4. Keep the Consent Command dropdown value on 'Default'
5. Now set the Analytics (corresponds with `analytics_storage`) and Ads (corresponds with
   `ad_storage`) values to the respective lookup table (type regex) variables we just created. [View example row settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W5z3.png)
6. It is advised to have the default consent tag fire as soon as possible on a page, so
   set the tag firing priority to 1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAruC.jpg
7. Add an All Pages trigger to the tag and then save it.
8. Now, we need to setup the `Update` tag for Google Consent Mode. This will allow you to update the settings whenever a user clicks on a consent banner. If you use Cookiebot, the click on the banner will generate events based on the type of consent given.
9. Create a Custom Event trigger, fill in the default Cookiebot event values `(cookieconsent_marketing|cookieconsent_statistics)` and enable the option `Use regex matching`, then save the trigger.
10. Finally, copy the original Google Consent Mode tag we just created. In the `Consent Command`  dropdown, select `Update`. Check that the correct lookup table variables are set for Advertising and Analytics [Google Consent Mode Update settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJZrx.png) and assign it the Custom Event trigger you just created.
11. Don't forget to update all your Google tags. If you have triggers setup that use a conditional check on cookie consent, you can remove these. Eg. If you have a pageview tag for Google Analytics that has a trigger for All Page where Consent level is XYZ, then remove the consent part from the trigger and just add a regular All Pages. Same goes for any custom event triggers you might use for ie. click tracking (generic events in GA). Keep in mind, this solution **only works for Google tags**, so make sure you still apply consent conditions in the triggers of tags like those for Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter etc. If you are unsure about anything, check with a legal advisor.
12. Test & publish, or ask me any questions you might have.

Answer (score -1):

To manage it from GTM you will find the tags dedicated to consent mode among the custom templates.

Comment: Can you link some documentation on how to enable consent mode using GTM custom templates. Whatever I found is not working.

Comment: Try to see it: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.simoahava.com/amp/custom-templates/consent-mode/